# AngularJS - How to combine identical, parallel $http/$resource requests in a factory

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

For sake of simplicity, assume that I have an AngularJS application where 2 controllers are executed at the same time, for different parts of the website. Both controllers need the same AJAX data from a singleton factory called `API` that looks something like this:

```
app.factory('API', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    getData: function(callback) {
      $http({method: 'GET', url: '/data'}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        callback(data);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Both controllers execute `API.getData(...)` **at the same time** (so before the first gets a response) and receive exactly the same data, but do different things with it. What would be the best approach to have the *second* (and subsequent) call to `getData` actually use the data from the first request, once it's there, instead of creating another AJAX call? The controllers know nothing about each other and should also work when there is only one of them to make this call.

Maybe I'm overcomplicating it, but the only solution I came up with, was to manually queue all `callback` functions in a factory-wide queue and then execute them together when the "singleton" AJAX call finishes. Is there a better way to do this?

I've read about `$q.all`, but it doesn't apply here (I think), since I actually only want to have a single request instead of multiple ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing in a callback, return the promise from the function. Then save the promise from the first $http call, so that when it is resolved, it resolved for everything that called the function. Something like this:

```
app.factory('API', ['$http', function($http){
  var dataPromise;
  return {
    getData: function() {
      if (!dataPromise)
      {
         dataPromise = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/data'});
      }
      return dataPromise          
    }
  };
}]);
```

Then in the controller you could do any number of things with the returned promise (See [promise documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)), but the functionally equivalent of the code above would be something like tis:

```
API.getData().success(function(data) {
    //my callback code
});
```

Comment: Huh, that's a good approach! Didn't think of that... will give it a try and report back later. :)

Comment: Can you please add what the code in the controller would look like with this approach?

Comment: Documentation for what you can do on the returned promise can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. The promise returned by `$http` has additional `success` and `error` functions. Call any of those methods with whatever callback you were passing into the service.

Comment: Actually, current docs say that you should use `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)`, don't they? :)

Comment: You can use either one. I'd probably prefer to use `then` so that you're not assuming you're getting back an httpPromise. I just posted the functionally equivalent to your original code. You can decide what's best for you to do with the returned promise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to your requirements, but you could always use the "resolve" functionality in your route configurations, to ensure that this data is already there before your view and your controllers load. If you are not familiar with it, you can see the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider).

Comment: Not really, since I don't want to make the users wait for the request to resolve - sometimes it can be a long running request. Plus, the controller might execute `API.getData()` on user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Put the data in `$rootScope` and then wait for it in the other controller.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. `getData()` request number 2 is executed while `getData()` request number 1 is still running and doesn't have any data (yet) to put in any scope. Plus, like I said, the controllers know nothing about each other or the order in which they want to get the data.